# how to form one to many recordset query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 db, wondering what the best way to form this set of queries is.

I would like to select all my users, which is easy enough with:

> Select * From Users

Each user will have a set of UserModules linked by User_ID. This is what I would like to know, if I can pull all this information out in one query?

One other thing, in my C# app how do I process the recordset and their sub-recordsets? Up until now I have been using the following, basically wondering if there is anything special I need to do to go with the query?

```
using (var reader_user = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader_user.Read())
    {
        MapUser(reader_user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can this is known as "Multiple Recordsets". Check Reader's NextResult();

```
using (var reader_user = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader_user.Read())
    {
        MapUser(reader_user);
    }

    reader_user.NextResult();

    while (reader_user.Read())
    {
        Whatever(reader_user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok fare enough, then what if you want to process creating a user object with multiple user_modules object in it?

Comment: C# objects or DB entities? You can't do anything additional in this connection with DB when reader is opened. No meter how many recordsets were returned. open connection, open reader, get results (create C# objects), close reader, create new Db entiteis, close connection...